# How to get program to print the reverse of a word AFTER a hyphen?

Tags: java, string, loops, reverse

I have the reverse part done, but I'm having trouble about the hyphen. Any help is appreciated! Also, the code so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print( "Enter a string of words that contains a hyphen: ");
    String word = kbd.next();
    for (int i = word.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {            
          System.out.print(word.charAt(i));    
    }
}
```

Example input:

```
low-budget
```

Required output:

```
tegdub (the reverse of the part after the hyphen)
```

Comment: what you mean? What you input and what is the expected output? To me everything looks fine

Comment: So say the user inputs "low-budget". I need to get this to print out the reverse of "budget" only.

Comment: okay let me work on it

Comment: Will the input string contain more than one hyphen characters?  If so, which part has to be reversed?

Comment: nope, just one is whats expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest possible solution I can think of (ofc there are other better solutions but this is my implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print( "Enter a string of words that contains a hyphen: ");
    String word = kbd.next();

    int loc = word.indexOf('-');    //Here I am trying to find the location of that hyphen

    for (int i = word.length()-1; i > loc; i--) { //Now print the rest of the String in reverse TILL that location where we found hyphen. Notic i > loc           
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));    
    }

        System.out.print(" ");

    for (int i = loc + 1; i < word.length(); i++) { //Now print the original String starting after the hyphen. Notice int i = loc + 1
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way (in one line):

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word.replaceAll(".*-", "")).reverse());
```

Edge cases handled for free:

- If there's no hyphen, the whole string is printed reversed
- If there's more than one hyphen, the last one is used. To use the first one, change the match regex to `"^.*?-"`
- If the string is blank, a blank is printed

Think about all the code that *didn't* need to be written to handle these (valid) input cases

Breaking down how this works:

1. `word.replaceAll(".*-", "")` does a replacement of all matches to the regex `.*-`, which means "everything up to and including the (last) hyphen", with a blank - effectively deleting the match
2. `new StringBuilder(...)` creates a `StringBuilder` initialized with the String passed into the constructor (from point 1). The only reason we need a `StringBuilder` is to use the `reverse()` method (`String` doesn't have it)
3. `reverse()` reverses the `StringBuilder`'s contents and returns it ready for the next call (see [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface))
4. Passing a non-String to `System.out.println` causes `String.valueOf()` to be invoked on the object, which in turn invokes the objects `toString()` method, which for a `StringBuilder` returns its contents

Voila!

Comment: Nice. I couldn't remember where I saw `reverse` before - `votes++;`

Comment: @Beatz explanation added. Note that learning a language means learning its libraries and classes. No one in the real world should be writing low-level code like yours when a straightforward (and readable) approach exists using the JDK. And if someone says anything about "performance", they obviously don't realize that the most important performance is that of your developers in producing working code.

Comment: @Bohemian I hope to be as efficient at code writing as you, one day. But for all intents and purposes, this code is meant to be basic, as it is meant to be review for my class.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (one-line) Java 8 stream-based solution for interest:

```
word.chars().skip(word.indexOf('-') + 1).mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char)c))
  .reduce("", (a, b) -> b + a).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Edge case treatment:

- Conveniently, if there's no hyphen, the *whole* string is printed in reverse. This is due to `indexOf(char)` returning `-1` in the case of not found, so the end result is skipping zero (`-1 + 1`)
- If more than one hyphen is present, only the first will be used to split the word
- A blank string prints nothing, because the `chars()` stream is empty

To print a blank when the input is blank, use this code instead:

```
System.out.println(word.chars().skip(word.indexOf('-') + 1)
  .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char)c)).reduce("", (a, b) -> b + a));
```

Notice the use of the alternate form of the `reduce()` method, wherein an identity value of a blank (`""`) is passed in, which is used in the case of an empty stream to guarantee a reduction result.

Answer (score 1):

First, split it based on the `-`. 
Then, go over the second part in reverse...

```
    String s = "low-budget";
    String[] t = s.split("-");
    for (int i = t[1].length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.print(t[1].charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: Im sorry, could you explain what the [ ] and t do? Im pretty new to all this.

Comment: t is a String array created by splitting s around the `-`. `[1]` gives the second string (budget) in the array. t[0] would be low. @Beatz.